# Need to add JCheckBox In JTable Dynamically

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jcombobox, renderer

I have two `JTable`. There are certain number of records in one `JTable`.

Once the first `JTable` is loaded I want to load equal number of `JCheckbox` to be created in the  second table.

I have this scenario ... vl pass both the tables in method `addCheckBox`.

```
private void addCheckBox(JTable procTableSrc, JTable procTableCk){

    CheckBoxRenderer checkBoxRenderer = new CheckBoxRenderer();
    EachRowRenderer rowRenderer = new EachRowRenderer();
    int rows = procTableSrc.getRowCount();

    DefaultTableModel dm = (DefaultTableModel)procTableCk.getModel();

    Object [] data = new Object[][]{{new Boolean(false)},{new Boolean(false)}}; 

    for(int i=1; i <=rows; i++){
        rowRenderer.add(i, checkBoxRenderer);           
        //model.addRow(new Object []{new Boolean(false)});
    }
}
```

Please help me with a code in achieving that.

Comment: You have not yet asked a specific and answerable question. What help *specifically* do you need? What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Can you show us any code? Tell us about any errors?  Please address these issues soon, else I fear your question will be closed as unanswerable.

Comment: you have problem with DefalutTableModel and EachRowRenderer, there no needed to define for CheckBoxRenderer for DefalutTableModel

Comment: Please see **Edit 1** in my answer below.

Comment: Please see **Edit 2** in my answer below.

Comment: are you means this `EachRowRenderer` http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Java-Document/Database-Client/executequery/org/underworldlabs/swing/table/EachRowRenderer.java.htm

Comment: _want to load equal number of JCheckbox to be created in the second table._ No, most probably you don't want to - but then it's hard to tell as you didn't yet bother to learn the technical vocabulary. Be sure you do so quickly, f.i. by reading the tutorial @Hovercraft linked to

Answer (score 5):

Thank you for your edits, but you still might want to show us more and tell us what errors your current code is causing.

Regarding your "CheckBoxRenderer" class, you don't need this.  Please read the JTable tutorial which you can find [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html).  There you will see that all you need to do is override your table model's `getColumnClass` method to return Boolean.class  for the column of interest for it to display checkboxes.

Luck.

**Edit 1**
Also what is with "row renderer", and what purpose does it serve?  To add information to your JTable, you must add rows to its model, and I don't see your code doing that.  Have a look at the DefaultTableModel API where you'll see the addRow(...) method which may help you a great deal.  Either that or create a new DefaultTableModel object with your data arrays. In fact, this is probably better since you can then override its getColumnClass() method to return Boolean for the column that needs to dislay check boxes.

**Edit 2**
Also this won't compile since you're declaring it as a one dimensional array and initializing it as a 2-dimensional array.:

```
Object [] data = new Object[][]
```

Consider doing the following:

- Create a 2-dimensional array of Object and have it hold your model's data.  The array's first index will be the the number of rows displayed in the JTable and the second will be the number of columns.
- Fill each column position with your Booleans.
- Create a new DefaultTableModel object, one that overrides getColumnClass(...) and has it return Boolean.class for the column that holds Booleans and needs to display check boxes.
- Give it a constructor that allows you to pass in the 2-D Object array and perhaps an array of String for the column headers. The first line of the constructor should be a call to the super constructor and you will need to pass the array parameters into this call.
- call setModel on your procTableCk object passing in this model that you've just created.

Comment: ASAP comment removed after his edit removing urgency and asap from his question.