# Using result set to add dynamic JCheckBox

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jcheckbox, defaulttablemodel

I saw this [Need to add JCheckBox In JTable Dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6972182/need-to-add-jcheckbox-in-jtable-dynamically) but it didn't help at all seeing my situation is similar but I am not sure how to add the `JCheckBox` after I have take the raw data from my database.

```
    public void fillAnyTable(ResultSet resultSet, JTable table)throws SQLException{

        //Create new table model
        DefaultTableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel();

        //Retrieve meta data from ResultSet
        ResultSetMetaData metaData = resultSet.getMetaData();

        //Get number of columns from metadata
        int columnCount = metaData.getColumnCount();

        //Get all column names from metadata and add columns to table
        for (int columnIndex = 1; columnIndex <= columnCount; columnIndex++){
            tableModel.addColumn(metaData.getColumnLabel(columnIndex));
        }
        //this is when I assume I can create a new column but now how to add the checkbox
        tableModel.addColumn("Check");
        //Create Array of Objects with size of Column count from metadata
        Object[] row = new Object[columnCount];

        //Scroll through Result Set
        while (resultSet.next()){
            //Get object from column with specific index of result set to array of objects
            for (int i = 0; i < columnCount; i++){
                row[i] = resultSet.getObject(i+1);

            }
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(row));
            //Now add row to table model with that array of objects as an argument
            tableModel.addRow(row);
        }
        //Now we add the table model to the table
        table.setModel(tableModel);
    }
}
```

**This is what the view looks like**

[image: This is what the view looks like]

Comment: *"..after I have take the raw data from my database."* Do you know how to do it from 'raw' data taken from hard coded values in the code itself? If so: 1) The MySQL tag is irrelevant. 2) Do that for the [mcve] posted as an [edit] to the question.

Answer (score 0):

> I am not sure how to add the JCheckBox after I have take the raw data from my database.

You don't add a JCheckBox. The TableModel holds data, not components. So you need to:

1. override the `getColumnClass(...)` method of the TableModel to return `Boolean.class` for the column where you want the check box. Then the table will use the proper renderer/editor for a check box.
2. add Boolean.FALSE to the TableModel when you add the data from the ResultSet.

So you just add the Boolean value when you are finished adding each column value to your row array:

```
//Now add row to table model with that array of objects as an argument
row[columnCount].add( Boolean.FALSE );
tableModel.addRow(row);
```

Of course you will also need to make your "row" array larger to hold this value.